# Android: How to create Custom View (for Canvas) within Fragment of ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-canvas

I want to create a custom view class within one of the pages of a ViewPager. When I try to do so with the xml file below my app crashes with the error: `FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.foo, PID: 21257 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.example.foo.NeckCanvasOverlay`

Below is my xml file for this page(fragment) of the ViewPager

**menu_fragment_neck.xml**

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/frets1to5" >

    <!-- Custom view for Canvas -->
    <com.example.foo.NeckCanvasOverlay
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
`
```

and this is the code I use to instantiate this fragment of the viewpager:

**FragmentNeckDisplayMenu.java**

```
public class FragmentNeckDisplayMenu extends Fragment {
private static View v;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment_neck_display,container,false); //ERROR HAPPENS HERE
    return v;
}
```

}

Whats preventing my custom view from being inflated properly?

**Edit: Included NeckCanvasOverlay & extended stack trace**

**NeckCanvasOverlay.java**

```
public class NeckCanvasOverlay extends View {
Paint mPaint;
private SparseArray<PointF> mActivePointers;

public NeckCanvasOverlay(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initView();
}

private void initView() {
    mActivePointers = new SparseArray<PointF>();  //creates array for pointer data
    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // get masked (not specific to a pointer) action
    int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked(); // commented out for test x
    // get pointer index from the event object
    int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
    // get pointer ID
    int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);

    switch (maskedAction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {  // New pointer, add it to the list of active pointers
            PointF f = new PointF();
            f.x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
            f.y = event.getY(pointerIndex);
            mActivePointers.put(pointerId, f);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: { // a pointer was moved
            int numberOfPointers = event.getPointerCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPointers; i++) {
                PointF f = mActivePointers.get(event.getPointerId(i));
                if (f != null) {
                    f.x = event.getX(i);
                    f.y = event.getY(i);
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointers.remove(pointerId);
            break;
        }
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // draw all pointers
    for (int size = mActivePointers.size(), i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        PointF point = mActivePointers.valueAt(i);
        if (point != null){
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            mPaint.setAlpha(170);
        }
        canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 100, mPaint);
    }
}
```

}

**Logcat Stacktrace**

```
    03-1123:31:29.2505492-5492/com.example.fooE/AndroidRuntime:FATALEXCEPTION:main
Process:com.example.foo,PID:5492
android.view.InflateException:BinaryXMLfileline#7:Errorinflatingclasscom.example.foo.NeckCanvasOverlay
atandroid.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:616)
atandroid.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
atandroid.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
atandroid.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
atandroid.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
atcom.example.foo.FragmentNeckDisplayMenu.onCreateView(FragmentNeckDisplayMenu.java:32)
atandroid.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
atandroid.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
atandroid.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
atandroid.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
atandroid.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
atandroid.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
atandroid.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
atandroid.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
atandroid.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
atandroid.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(ViewPager.java:700)
atcom.example.foo.PlayFrets.configMenu(PlayFrets.java:127)
atcom.example.foo.NoteFileLoader.onPostExecute(NoteFileLoader.java:125)
atcom.example.foo.NoteFileLoader.onPostExecute(NoteFileLoader.java:9)
atandroid.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
atandroid.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
atandroid.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
atandroid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
atandroid.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(NativeMethod)
atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Causedby:java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:<init>[classandroid.content.Context,interfaceandroid.util.AttributeSet]
atjava.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
atjava.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:495)
atandroid.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:580)
atandroid.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
atandroid.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
atandroid.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
atandroid.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
atcom.example.foo.FragmentNeckDisplayMenu.onCreateView(FragmentNeckDisplayMenu.java:32) 
atandroid.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786) 
atandroid.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947) 
atandroid.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126) 
atandroid.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739) 
atandroid.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489) 
atandroid.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486) 
atandroid.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141) 
atandroid.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073) 
atandroid.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919) 
atandroid.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(ViewPager.java:700) 
atcom.example.foo.PlayFrets.configMenu(PlayFrets.java:127) 
atcom.example.foo.NoteFileLoader.onPostExecute(NoteFileLoader.java:125) 
atcom.example.foo.NoteFileLoader.onPostExecute(NoteFileLoader.java:9) 
atandroid.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632) 
atandroid.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177) 
atandroid.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645) 
atandroid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
atandroid.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(NativeMethod) 
atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: post NeckCanvasOverlay class as well

Comment: Post the code of neckcanvasoverlay as issue exists there

Comment: Also, post the full stack trace.  Usually there's another one under that which says the real problem.

Comment: I've made the requested additions.

Comment: No one knows what's going wrong here??